# PFQueryTableViewController's loading view doesn't disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a pretty simple query that returns the list of a user's relations. It's working perfectly, but has a little problem. When the user hasn't got any contacts the `PFQueryTableViewController`'s loading view doesn't disappears despite it should, because the query returns a nil.

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.contacts = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"contacts"];

    PFQuery *query = [self.contacts query];

    [query orderByAscending:@"username"];

    return query;


}
```